# Complex queries in CouchDB across multiple documents

Tags: join, query, couchdb

I'm relatively new to CouchDB (more specifically Cloudant if it matters) and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around something.

Assume the following (simplified) document examples:

```
{ "docType": "school", "_id": "school1", "state": "CA" }
{ "docType": "teacher", "_id": "teacher1", "age": "40", "school": "school1" }
```

I want to find all the teachers aged 40 in California.

Maybe my mind is still stuck on SQL world, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to run a query that uses data from different documents...

PS. let me know if this is more suited to StackOverflow...

Answer (score 0):

For quick one time queries I would use [_find](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html), for permanent ones where performance is important I would create a [view](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/ddocs.html#view-functions) for this.

Views are very well explained in the booklet ["Writing and Querying MapReduce Views in CouchDB: Tools for Data Analysts"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449303129).

Answer (score 0):

You can join on related documents within the same database (see CouchDB documentation topic: [Joins With Views - Linked Documents](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/joins.html)).

The documents from the question:

> ```
> { "docType": "school", "_id": "school1", "state": "CA" }
> { "docType": "teacher", "_id": "teacher1", "age": "40", "school": "school1" }
> ```

For this create a view, which allows filtering on the main document. The view has a `map` function which does the join:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.school && doc.age === 40) {
    emit([ doc._id, doc.age ], { _id: doc.school });
  }
}
```

Note the filter on the `age` field of the teacher document.

This view is to be queried using the parameter `include_docs=true` (this parameter is required to get the joined document details), for example:

```
curl -X GET http://usr:<pwd>@127.0.0.1:5984/my_db/_design/my_design/_view/my_view?include_docs=true
```

For example, the output:

```
{
   "total_rows":1,
   "offset":0,
   "rows":[
      {
         "id":"teacher1",
         "key":[
            "teacher1",
            "40"
         ],
         "value":{
            "_id":"school11"
         },
         "doc":{
            "_id":"school1",
            "_rev":"1-0be327d3b2c9d07a4f143d93067b46c6",
            "docType":"school",
            "state":"CA"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This JSON result can be further processed / filtered for the schools in the state of "CA" (in an application).